How to change brightness level up down programmatically
I use this PowerShell code to change volume level up down
# 174 down | 175 up
(New-Object -Com WScript.Shell).SendKeys([char]175)

I want to do the same with screen brightness up down.
I do this by pressing FN + F11/ F12 with Keyboard.
Refer to WshShell.SendKeys, I didn't find the FN key.
How can I do it with a script?
change brightness level up down.

(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,100)

Thanks much. How if using SendKeys method?

This might get you part of the way:
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyDown")
if you hit a key after that you'll get results for the key your pressed the CHAR code for it and a few other items.

-@ThomSchumacher Thanks. I've tried. $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyDown") can detect almost all the Keyboard buttons except the one FN

Does this answer your question? How to press the Fn + function keys on Windows?

asked 6 years ago, and technology is developing every second.

this hasn't.  Fn key is still low-level which is not accessible programmatically.
